# update datagridview by my method?

Tags: datagridview

The following is the code to save the changes made in 'datagridview' to my database.
But the code just copies last record's values into all other records.

What is the problem?

```
   public void update_tbl(string tbl_name)
    {
         try
        {
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.Rows)
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "update [" + tbl_name + "] set tf='" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()+"'";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            this.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line of code and add a where clause

Your code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update [" + tbl_name + "] set tf='" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()+"'";
```

Expected code:

```
   cmd.CommandText = "update [" + tbl_name + "] set tf='" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()+"' where SomeUniqueField=" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

The above code